# Get a token index from stanford corenlp

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to get the index of a token using CoreNLP. I can get all the token annotations like POS, NER, but however the index returns `null`.
Here is the code:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentenceIndexAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.IndexAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.IndexedWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;    

protected StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
private void getPipeline(){
    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, parsing
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse");
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
}

private Annotation annotatedocument(String text) {
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    return document;    
}

private  void  getAnnotation(String sentence){  
    Annotation annotation = annotatedocument(sentence);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    int numSent=sentences.size();
    assert (numSent == 1):"Number of sentences in annotation  is > 1: " + numSent;

    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {  
        List<CoreLabel> tokens = sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class);
        for (CoreLabel token: tokens) { 
            String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
            Integer index= token.get(IndexAnnotation.class);
            String pos=token.getString(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I get word and POS correct but index is `null`.

Comment: Strange... This should always be set. Can you print out the `keySet()` of one of the tokens?

Comment: CoreAnnotations$ValueAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$TextAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$OriginalTextAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$BeforeAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$AfterAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$PartOfSpeechAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$LemmaAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$BeginIndexAnnotation
CoreAnnotations$EndIndexAnnotation.

I do get  Begin and EndIndex correct, but I am now confused why we have two indexes for a token. And what index does Indexed word class contain?

Comment: Hi, what version of Stanford CoreNLP are you using?  When I run your code through a sample example I see IndexAnnotation present.  As for BeginIndex and EndIndex, those are set by the parse annotator.  You should be seeing an IndexAnnotation for each token.

Comment: I am using version 3.4.

Comment: If you try upgrading to 3.5.2 does the problem go away?

Comment: Yes, upgrading to version 3.5.2 solved it. Thanks